# Jquery: Scroll to last <li>

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, offset, scrolltop

I'm using the following to scroll to the last `<li>` in an unordered list:

`$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $('ul#cart-items li').offset().top});`

How can I change this to scroll to the last `<li>` in the unordered list, but also offset it about 30px from the top?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $('ul#cart-items li:last').offset().top - 30});
```

but + or - the 30 at the end to achieve your desired offset?

Comment: For some reason the `li:last` isn't producing any results. Tested in Webkit and Firefox

Comment: My mistake, I needed to specify `li.item:last` as there are more `li` within the cart-items.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: $('ul#cart-items li:last').offset().top+30});
```

Here it is..